# django : 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a Login but it doesn't work.
the error is 
form.is_valid() return False and

> 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

I can't figure out out is the problem.

**user/forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'style': 'width:100%; height:100%;'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'style': 'width:100%; height:100%;'}))

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].label = "이메일"
        self.fields['password'].label = "비밀번호"

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        try:
            user = models.User.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return self.cleaned_data
            else:
                self.add_error("password", forms.ValidationError(
                    "비밀번호가 틀렸습니다."))
        except models.User.DoesNotExist:
            self.add_error("email", forms.ValidationError(
                "존재하지 않는 계정입니다."))
```

**users/views.py**

```
class LoginView(mixins.LoggedOutOnlyView, View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, "users/login.html", {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")

            get_user_name = user_models.User.objects.get(email=email)
            user = authenticate(
                request, username=get_user_name, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse("cores:home"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a local variable with the return value of the `super()` call. In your fields you'd no longer call the `self.cleaned_data` variant but the local variable `cleaned_data`. Also return the `cleaned_data` at the end of the `def clean()` method - even if errors occurred.

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        ...

        # Don't forget to return the cleaned_data after everything
        return cleaned_data
```

This is documented in the django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: I already read and try it, but it doesn't work. Though, Thank you very much!

Comment: I've test your and my setup both, both working properly. Any chance it has any old `*.pyc` files in memory?

Comment: I'm not sure... but all the files are saved and there is no old files. form.is_valid() is still False.

Comment: Please insert the full stack trace and add the import-lines to your code. Also I've updated my answer about returning the cleaned_data in the clean method - though this will most-likely not solve your problem.